# Does it matter if strongSwan runs on different namespace in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a strongSwan VPN connection running on my kubernates. I did create separate namespace for strongSwan configurations and separate namespace for the server. Now it’s not working and my question is can I separate those two using namespaces?

Comment: can you share logs of strongSwan pod? also how you deploy strongSwan configurations? [like configMap,secrets]. if you're mounting configurations through configMaps, in this case, strongSwan pod couldn't mount separate namespace's configmap

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I use helm for deployment and I see that all pods run well on specified nodes and separate namespace. I ran helm test vpn and it did pass all required tests. So The tunnel works well. It just doesn’t work on the server. So now i’m thinking that maybe my server and my strongSwan do not talk with each other? StrongSwan VPN has it’s own external ip and my server has as well. Do I need to do some proxy or something?